# Count values in mysql database rows

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table in my database that looks like this.

```
id    count
-----------
1      23
2      20
3      12
4      4
```

The "count" column will periodically change. How would I add all the values in the count column and display them on the front end? So for example, in this case they would add up to 59.

Comment: Did you do any research at all? The MySQL documentation lists all the functions and operators at your disposal; it is obvious in this case which to pick if you peruse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sum(count) from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`count`) FROM myTable
```